# Micronaut: Project with features "postgres" and "testcontainers" fails with "Error instantiating bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource]"

Tags: micronaut

I've set up a fresh Micronaut project facing the error

```
Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]
```

when executing initially set up test cases via `$ ./gradlew clean build`.

I've boiled it down to the following procedure:

```bash
$ mn create-app --inplace --build=gradle_kotlin --jdk=17 --lang=kotlin --test=spock --features=postgres,testcontainers testing
| Application created at [...]

$ ./gradlew clean build

> Task :kaptKotlin
[...]

> Task :test

TestingSpec > initializationError FAILED
    io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException at DefaultBeanContext.java:1921
        Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException at DefaultBeanContext.java:2367
            Caused by: io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException at DefaultHttpClient.java:2237

1 test completed, 1 failed

> Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file://[...]/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

[...]

BUILD FAILED in 14s
22 actionable tasks: 22 executed
```

HTML report shows mentioned

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [javax.sql.DataSource] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

Message: Not Found
Path Taken: DataSource.dataSource(DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfiguration) --> DataSource.dataSource([DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfiguration])
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1921)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:249)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3326)
    [...]
```

What went wrong?

Regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems problem arises from `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` that has following preconfigured content:

```yaml
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:12:///postgres
    driverClassName: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

Adding "default/dummy" credentials solves the problem for me:

```yaml
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:12:///postgres
    driverClassName: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    username: 'sa'
    password: ''
```

So I recommend to add creation of this credential configs to the process of `mn --create-app` if feature `testcontainers` is choosen :-)

Christian